# How to call "simplest" random floating variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In one of answer from @DmitriT, got the relevant answer to declare the random floating variable

```
         ${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextFloat(0.0f\, 100f),)}
```

But here in the same function, how to restrict to one decimal alone. I have tried like:

```
        ${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextFloat(0.0f\, 100f).format("%.1f"))}
```

but doesn't work. any suggestions pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need a [float number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) there, if you need only one decimal place you can consider invoking normal JMeter's [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) twice using dot as the separator like:

```
${__Random(0,9,)}.${__Random(0,9,)}
```

If you do a benchmark like described in the [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) article you will see that the `__Random()` approach executes faster and has smaller footprint.

Comment: I need the data within 0 to 9 only, which mean 0.1 to 9.0. but above function leads to 0.1 to 9.9 as well.

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem.

```
 ${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextFloat(1.0f\,7.0f).round(1))}
```